# increase number of oppened files at the same time. Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

In Ubuntu Mate 16.04.4LTS, every time I run the command:

```
$ ulimit -a
```

I get:

```
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

I tried to increase this limit adding at the /etc/security/limits.conf the command:

```
  myusername      hard   nofile    100000
```

but doesn't matter this value 1024 persist if I run  ulimit -a. I rebooted the system after the modification yet the problem persist.
  Also, if I run

```
  ulimit -n 100000
```

I get the response:

```
  ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

and if I run

```
   sudo ulimit -n 100000
```

I get:

```
   sudo: ulimit: command not found
```

Any ideas on how to increse that limit?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just after I posted this question. Based on:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/162229/how-do-i-increase-the-open-files-limit-for-a-non-root-user

I also edited:

```
  /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

and added the following line to the end:

```
  session required pam_limits.so
```

All works now.

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash` under `ulimit`:

> ```
> -n     The maximum number of open file descriptors (most systems do not allow this value to be set)
> ```

Maybe your problem is simply that your system does not support modifying this limit?